# Set a list of strings in request payload

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, arraylist

I need to pass this request payload in REST API.. for below data list array, I need to set it to request even if I'm not getting from a client like a constant string-list.

these are my java classes, can anyone help me where I need to set this

```
{
"ph":"2019201234",
"customerId":"3504241",
"data":[
    "./ManagedObjects/Phone/Manufacturer",
    "./ManagedObjects/**something",
    "./ManagedObjects/**something",

    ]

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping(Constants.Endpoints.**)
public ShowParametersResponse getParams(@RequestBody  ShowParametersRequest showParametersRequest) {
    log.info("Got request as : " + showParametersRequest);
    returnMapper.getParams(showParametersRequest);
}
```

**Mapper class:**

```
public ShowParametersResponse getParams(ShowParametersRequest showParametersRequest) {
    log.info("Fetching data from wireless");
    ShowParametersResponse showParametersResponse  = Service.getParams(showParametersRequest);
    log.info("Fetched data/ mapping done.");
    return showParametersResponse;
}
```

**Service class:**

```
public ShowParametersResponse  getParams(ShowParametersRequest showParametersRequest) {

    ResponseEntity<ShowParametersResponse> res = restTemplate.postForEntity(
            properties.getEndpoint() + Constants.Endpoints.***, showParametersRequest,
            ShowParametersResponse.class);
    log.info(res.getBody().toString());
    return res.getBody();
}
```

**Request class:**

```
public class ShowParametersRequest {
    @JsonProperty("ph")
    private String ph;
    @JsonProperty("customerId")
    private String customerId;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<String> data = null;

    @JsonProperty("ph")
    public String getPh() {
        return ph;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ph")
    public void setPh(String ph) {
        this.ph = ph;
    }

    @JsonProperty("customerId")
    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("customerId")
    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.imei = customerId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check at the boundaries (read: where you receive the request payload) if you received something as part of `data` (or not)...and add them accordingly. You can also use an interceptor/filter for a specific route and add them there before it gets into the request handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the list as below, You can check for if a list is empty from client-side then can add it according to your requirements

```
List<String> constStringList = Arrays.asList("./ManagedObjects/Phone/Manufacturer",
                "./ManagedObjects/**something",
                "./ManagedObjects/**something");
```

---

```
@PostMapping(Constants.Endpoints.**)
public ShowParametersResponse getParams(@RequestBody  ShowParametersRequest showParametersRequest) {

     List<String> constStringList = Arrays.asList("./ManagedObjects/Phone/Manufacturer",
                    "./ManagedObjects/**something",
                    "./ManagedObjects/**something");    

    showParametersRequest.setData(constStringList);  
    log.info("Got request as : " + showParametersRequest);
    returnMapper.getParams(showParametersRequest);
}
```